# Function to return int values from a column - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm having a problem returning an integer value from an identity column where I only want the values greater than 5 which will be used in another select. The code I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get_Dragon_ID]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I INT
    SELECT @I = Dragon_ID
    FROM Dragons
    WHERE Dragon_ID > 5
    RETURN @I
END

-- How it's being used:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Discovered_Dragons]
AS
SELECT
    dbo.fn_Get_Dragon_ID() AS Dragon_ID,  
    [dbo].[fn_Set_Tracker](ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) % 7 + 1)
    AS Assigned_Tracker
FROM
    [dbo].[stDrgnInbnd0]
```

The output I expected:

```
Dragon_ID   Assigned_Tracker
6           Hiccup
7           Camicazi
8           Hiccup
9           Hiccup
10          Tuffnut
11          Snotface Snotlout
.
.
.
```

What I'm actually getting:

```
Dragon_ID   Assigned_Tracker
305         Hiccup
305         Camicazi
305         Hiccup
305         Hiccup
305         Tuffnut
305         Snotface Snotlout
.
.
.
```

I've searched the site and Google'd my brains out but I must be stating the issue incorrectly. Thanks for any assistance.

**UPDATE:**
The Dragon_ID column is an identity column - (1,1), which I am attempting to get the rows higher than 5 (the row count of the initial table) and the row id's after an insert.

@Gordon Linoff: I tried earlier to use the code inline as you suggested however :

```
declare @I int
SELECT
    (SELECT @I as Dragon_ID
FROM Dragons
WHERE Dragon_ID > 5),  
    stDrgnInbnd0.Dragon_Name AS Dragon_Type,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Sighting_Date,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Sighting_Location,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Pack_Status,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Day_OR_Night_Sleep,
    [dbo].[fn_Set_Tracker](ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) % 7 + 1)
    AS Assigned_Tracker
FROM
    [dbo].[stDrgnInbnd0]
```

And got the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Thanks again.

Comment: The variable @I is getting last value from the selected dragon Ids. That's the reason you are getting 305.

Comment: The way you are passing the value to `fn_Set_Tracker` function in the same way perhaps you can pass some value, compute in the function and return. Unless you show the input schema and the requirement coming up with a solution is difficult.

Comment: @fiveelements I realize the last value is being used, the column I'm selecting is of type int and I need the row numbers after an insert. I will update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is there some reason you need a function rather than a view?

Comment: Gordon's answer is spot on for the issue at hand. However I have a feeling that what you really need here is just a join between those two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is a *scalar* function so it returns a single value.  That single value is determined by this logic:

```
SELECT @I = Dragon_ID
FROM Dragons
WHERE Dragon_ID > 5;
```

What this is doing is cycling through the `Dragons` table and returns the "last" encountered value.  Because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, this is an indeterminate row in the table.

In your case, the "intedeterminate" row is probably the row with the highest id.  This is an observations; **there are no guarantees.**

It sounds like you want a *table-valued function*.  If so, you need to both fix the function *and* adjust your query to move the function call into the `from` clause.  Actually, though, I see no reason for a function at all -- a view or just putting the code inline would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at `table-valued` functions, however, I tried inlining the code earlier and got "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." I'll post what I'm using above.

Comment: I re-read your answer and saw `view`, I completely didn't think about it as a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a join which would look like the select below.

The problem is I don't know what column in stDrgnInbnd0 to join on so I put "?" there.

```
SELECT Dragon_ID,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Dragon_Name AS Dragon_Type,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Sighting_Date,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Sighting_Location,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Pack_Status,
    stDrgnInbnd0.Day_OR_Night_Sleep,
    [dbo].[fn_Set_Tracker](ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) % 7 + 1)
    AS Assigned_Tracker
FROM Dragons
join stDrgnInbnd0 ON stDrgnInbnd0.?  = Dragons.DragonID 
WHERE Dragon_ID > 5
```

What are all the columns in stDrgnInbnd0?